# is it possible to update mysql with timed intervals without a client request

Tags: php, ajax

I have working on game where users can send each other challenges. These challenges have timed intervals, say hours, days etc. 
When a user logs in the times set can be retrieved through mysql then displayed as a countdown clock using java script to show and countdown remaining time. If the time runs out the database can be updated to display this. This works fine if users are logged in but what if the time set ends when nobody is logged in.
So is there a way of running something constantly on the server to check these countdowns and change the database if the time has ran out or would it work better check the timer when a user views the challenge then act accordingly.

to clarify:

Option 1. Automated script that runs on a server checking the times of each challenge. Either by having a computer constantlylogged in running an ajajar request with an interval timer. (Preferably without a computer and ajax)

Option 2: when a user views the challenge the time is worked out. If the time has ended update this in the database so the challenge now shows up as ended.

If option 1 is possible is it better and how would this Work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use dates. Go with `date_created` and `date_expired`. If the current time exceeds the date expired time, etc etc.

Comment: I would go with this; calculate the date/time the moment you know it, and store that. No reason to wait until it expires to update it.

Comment: Looks good but is it possible to set times as well as dates created and date expired, so a user can set an exact time for the challenge to end say start 4pm on the 2nd to end 3pm on the 5th

Comment: These are just names for the columns. Set the data type to `DATETIME` - read up on that. It'll be 2014-01-31 23:59:59

Comment: Thanks for the help that has really simplified what I wanted to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking to delete the expired challenges? or set a flag, so the user knows they existed but expired?

depending on your SQL version, look into 'Events'. it's similar to a CRON job, but is run on the SQL server. i would say this is a good option if available to you.

Comment: Setting a flag so that the challenge can still be viewed but displays that the challenge has expired